# Why there is theta in index of gradient symbol in gradient descent update formula for MAML?

Tags: neural-networks, loss-functions, gradient-descent, gradient, meta-learning

In [this](https://arxiv.org/abs/1703.03400) MAML paper, they use following formula of gradient descent update (see page 3, algorithm 1):

$$
\varTheta '\ =\varTheta \ −\ \alpha \nabla _{\varTheta }\mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{T}_{i}}( f_{\varTheta })
$$

My question is, what is the reason of having theta in subscript after gradient (nabla) ?

Specifically, why is it not like this:

$$
\displaystyle \varTheta '\ =\varTheta \ −\ \alpha \nabla \mathcal{L}_{\mathcal{T}_{i}}( f_{\varTheta }) \  
$$

In other words why is not enough to tell it like just gradient of loss function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That means *gradient with respect to $\theta$*. In the context, there is little uncertainty and probably anyone reading the paper can understand that it is gradient wrt $\theta$ even if they hadn't used the subscript notation but there is no harm in being precise, especially in published work.

It's like writing $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \theta}$, instead of $f'$.